# Replacing data in a csv from "" to "null" powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, null

I am reading a CSV in a powershell script. The script pulls specific data, and then writes it to a different CSV. Is there a way I can replace any "" values with the word "null"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that should give you something to start with...:

```
@'
Foo,Bar
"",""
Alfa,Beta
Gamma,""
"",Delta
'@ | ConvertFrom-csv | Foreach-Object { 
    foreach ($Property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Property.Value)) {
            $_.($Property.Name) = 'NULL'
        }
    }
    $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You *could* try just replace: "" with "NULL", but if you have more complicated data it may give you some unexpected results, working on PSObject.Properties collection does not have this flaw/ risk.

Comment: Thanks for revealing the PSObject; was not aware of that. Do you happen to have any links to articles discussing PSObject? Neither a quick web search nor the PowerShell spec was terribly fruitful.